# How to convert .ods to latex?

Tags: libreoffice, latex

When I use calc2latex I receive the error message "BASIC Runtime Error: Object Variable not set"

Using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the `Main` Macro:

[image]